# Are pointers dereferenced by default inside of methods?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm confused by methods on structs in Go. I've following along in a tutorial in which they have:

```
func (p *Page) save() error {
    filename := p.Title + ".txt"
    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}
```

From my understanding, `p` is pointer and you would need to dereference the pointer before retrieving a property for example:

```
filename := (*p).Title + ".txt"
```

The only way this makes sense to me is if the dot is acting like `->` in C++. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted, accept my upvote.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, the pointer to the struct is automatically dereferenced. From the [spec on selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors):

> The following rules apply to selectors:
>
> 1. For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer or interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in `T`
>      where there is such an `f`. If there is not exactly one `f` with
>      shallowest depth, the selector expression is illegal.
>
> ...
>
> 3. As an exception, if the type of `x` is a named pointer type and `(*x).f` is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a
>      method), `x.f` is shorthand for `(*x).f`.

Therefore, the following two statements are the same (with the first being preferred):

```
filename := p.Title + ".txt"
filename := (*p).Title + ".txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to deference pointers or use a special access operator to access the fields of a struct in Go.

```
myRef := &ILikeCompositeLiteralInitilization{}
fmt.Println(myRef.Dereferenced);
```

is functionally equivalent to;

```
fmt.Printn((*myRef).Dereferenced);
```

Possibly worth noting that the behavior for functions is not like this. Meaning, I would have to dereference to invoke a method who's recieving type is the value and not a pointer. IE;

```
func (*ILikeCompositeLiteralInitilization) PointerVersion()
func (ILikeCompositeLiteralInitilization) ValueVersion()

myRef.PointerVersion() // compiler likes this

myRef.ValueVersion() // won't compile

(*myRef).ValueVersion() // compiler is OK with this
```

Basically, with functions no implicit dereference or address of type operation will occur, your code won't compile.

Comment: Are you sure about the `myRef.ValueVersion() // won't compile` ? From what I read elsewhere `there's "magic" happening that allows you to call a method with a pointer receiver on a non-pointer value and vice versa`. I have tested your use case and it worked.