# how golang starts a task independent of the main task

Tags: go, asynchronous

How golang starts a task, the main task returns, but the asynchronous task can continue to run. It is best to control the timeout of the task, such as through ctx control.

my code is

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func asyncTask() {
    fmt.Println("task start")
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("task end")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main start ")

    go asyncTask()

    fmt.Println("task...")
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("main end")
}
```

i hope the main function does not need to sleep. The task continues to run after returning.

Comment: When `main` returns, program ends.

Answer (score 6):

When `main` exits, the program ends and all goroutines shut down. `main` must have a way to wait until all goroutines end. You're correct that there are better ways than sleeping; sleeping in concurrent code is a red flag. Here are some basic options.

Simplest is to [use a channel](https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func worker(done chan bool) {
    fmt.Print("working...")
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("done") 

    done <- true
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    go worker(done) 

    <-done
}
```

main makes a channel and passes it into the worker. `<-done` causes main to wait until there's something to read. Once worker is done, it sends a true value down the done channel (the value doesn't matter), main reads it and can continue.

For more workers use [WaitGroups](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func worker(id int) {
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d starting\n", id)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Worker %d done\n", id)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup   

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            worker(i)
        }()
    }   

    wg.Wait()
}
```

main creates a [sync.WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup). Each time it starts a goroutine it adds 1 to the group. Each worker is wrapped in a goroutine which will call `wg.Done` when the work is done subtracting 1 from the group. `wg.Wait()` will wait until the WaitGroup is back to 0 indicating all workers are done.

Answer (score 2):

The go runtime manages all goroutines. Your question seems to intend to ask how to guarantee the execution of the code in a go routine even when the main has finished its work. The answer to this is waitgroups and the sync package.

Your toy example could have a larger wait time in the go routine to test what would happen.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func asyncTask(sleepTime int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Printf("task start %ds\n", sleepTime)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleepTime) * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("task end :%ds\n", sleepTime)
    if wg != nil {
        defer wg.Done()
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("->main start ")
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go asyncTask(6, nil)
    go asyncTask(4, &wg)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("->main end")
    wg.Wait()
}
```

The first one does not reach the end, while the second one does (even sleeping for a second longer).

I recommend you read the [GoByExample simple example](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups), the [sync documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/sync), this fantastic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66767168/4343913) on the sync package use with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to put sleep in main thread, the thing is in golang main thread is the last thread which exit the program,

By default there will be a main thread so condition is that all the other thread which is being initiated by main thread must complete themselves.

For doing the other complete we can use multiple things

- Channel

  Channal are the conduit between two thread to communicate.
- WaitGroup

  Waitgroup are generally used when one or more thread or worker are doing some task, asynchronously, waitgroup contains stats of the other thread are they done or not.